# Autolock iOS device while in camera mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an app where the user can scan barcodes and it will display information in realtime over the camera's view. Is it possible to have the iPad autolock after a set time while in the video feed? It is very likely that the user will set down the iPad while the app is running for the scenario in which it will be used, and this would pose a significant problem for battery life.

Comment: Why not just let the user set that for themselves. Most people set the auto lock on their iPad between 1 to 5 minutes, and by default it is 1 minute. Why force something which is already there.

Comment: @CodeMonkey That is what is desired -- however iOS will not automatically lock the device while the camera feed is being displayed.

Comment: Cool, I understand what you're asking, but unfortunately the answer is no. You can prevent the lock screen with sleepwithtimeinterval for a while or indefinitely but to force the lock there is no way so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're unfortunately not going to be able to do this unless you do a round-about hack assuming the user's device is already set to lock after 1 minute.

If the latter case is true you can disable the `idleTimerDisabled` and after your period of inactivity re-enable the idleTimer which will then trigger the phone to be able to lock again after 1 minute.

Comment: The app is an in-house, enterprise app so we have control over the tablet's settings. I'll give your suggestion a try.

Answer (score 0):

An app can prevent a device from going to sleep (see `UIApplication idleTimerDisabled`) but there is no API to make a device go to sleep. Whether a device goes to sleep after a certain period of time is up to the user, not an app.